Is it possible to build a Full-Spectrum White Laser?
I've recently read some novels set in Neal Asher's Polity series, and I have a few questions. For starters, is it possible to build a full spectrum white laser weapon, as used by the Atheter starship in infinity engine and Dragon in the rise of the Jain trilogy? I want to use one as a weapon on a ship that the plot pivots around, The United Space Navy Heavy Cruiser Fredrick Douglass* However, if superior alternatives are available, please do not hesitate to tell me. Power is not a problem, the Fredrick has the juice to spare, but please keep it below the average power used by Arkansas in a year. Please.
By the way, this is my first question, and I am a layman, with a little understanding of physics. (I know the second law of thermodynamics is a bastard.)

The United Space of America is the owner of the ship, and has claims on the local star, currently holding the 13 colony star systems, and Sol.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi @AspiringAuthor, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. That comment from the automated Community BOT is a red flag indicating that your post failed to meet Stack Exchanges' basic "good question" metrics. I suspect the problem is that your question is long with complex grammar thanks to the book and ship references. SE really likes clean, well-focused posts and since we have a lot of English-as-a-second-language users, it's appreciated by many. It might also have become confused with your use of an asterisk to reference a footnote. As you can see, asterisks have a non-footnote meaning here.

If you say "full-spectrum energy beam" without the laser component, my mind immediately goes to synchrotron radiation, which is notable because its spectrum ranges from the far infrared into the xray. In the visible spectrum, it'd usually look bluish-white, and it has a useful built-in explanation of why it's so dangerous (it's an extremely bright x-ray source).

Why? Using a white laser as a weapon is inefficient some of your wavelengths will be ineffective. What would be usefull is a tuneable laser which emits one frequency which can be changed to match the target and desired effect.

A full-spectrum white laser sounds like an oxymoron to my ears. Lasers, by definition, are coherent beams of light, meaning that all the photons act in unison where all their individual waves line up exactly (apologies if I messed up the exact details). This is only ever possible with one wavelength; it's impossible for two waves of differing lengths to line up exactly! Hence why lasers always come in one color. A full-spectrum white laser would be a lightbulb. If anyone sees that my understanding of lasers is wrong, please correct me!

It mostly depends on your definition of white.
White lasers are a thing for at least 9 years, and I have had colleagues working on making them possible for at least 19 years.
You can read more here:

A team of researchers from Arizona State University has shown that a new breed of semiconductor lasers can emit light across the entire visible spectrum, providing the full range of different colors that are required to make white laser light. These new lasers are made from three sheets of semiconductor, each just a few microns in thickness, that are held in parallel. Each of the sheets can emit one of the three elementary colors — red, green or blue — and depending on how their output is tuned, they can produce any color in the spectrum. When their entire output is combined, that means they can also produce white laser light.

As you can read, that white laser is made by mixing only 3 colors, in a similar way to how white was achieved on old CRT screens by lighting 3 pixels: blue, red and green.
First white LEDs even used just two colors: yellow and blue. In both cases, when the colors are perceived together, they are seen as white.
If you instead want to have a (quasi)continuous spectrum covering from red to violet, you might want to use several free electron lasers, each emitting at a different wavelength. It would be terribly complicated, but usually the militaries are not to bugged by cost aspects as civilians do.
However here I have to challenge your premise: what's the point of having a white laser? If you have a lot of energy and your target is vulnerable at a specific color, it's better to dump all the energy in that color, rather than spreading it where it would yield less or nothing at all.
Firing a white laser at a target is like showering a thick steel plate with arrows, stones and piercing bullets, when you know only the bullets will deal some damage.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

What you are looking for might be a supercontinuum laser. It uses a normal pumped single wavelength laser and a non-linear process to cause massive spectral broadening of the light beam. There may be different ways to do this, but the one I am most familiar with usually involves very short laser pulses passed through a specially engineered optical fiber. The picture below [source] shows an example of a supercontinuum spectrum.

While it may be argued that the supercontinuum is not generated directly from the laser itself, the beam can retain many of the properties typically associated with laser beams, such as high brightness, low angular divergence and tight spatial confinement.
A supercontinuum laser with the sort of power that I imagine you would need for your spaceship's white laser weapon has probably not been built yet, but it would probably be possible for an engineering department with a sufficiently large budget.
Some other interesting light sources that might fit your bill are synchrotron light sources and free-electron lasers. These tend to be extremely large, but I got the impression that you want something very powerful, so it may need to be very large anyway.

Just to comment: the very short pulses are used because you need very high intensity for the nonlinear optics to apply. But the repetition rate (number of pulses / sec) can be so high that you don't even realize it's pulsed - cutting edge lasers can go above 10kHz.

@Neinstein Yes, the supercontinuum laser in our lab uses a femtosecond laser with a repetition rate of 50 MHz.

Wouldn't this light source diverge a great deal over long distances?

@RobertRapplean What makes you think that?

@jkej Sweet! My institute is focused on ultrashort+ultrahigh intensity and in that regime it's a big deal we managed to implement a 100kHz few-femtosecond laser. Seems I was conservative with that happens if you loosen this focus :)

@RobertRapplean There is the difference between spatial coherence of a beam, temporal coherence of a beam and collimation. These properties, generally speaking, are independent of each other. Spatial coherence means there is a fixed phase relation betewen two different points in a beam, i.e. how well behaved is the beam in space. Temporal coherence means there exists a fixed phase relation between different points in time at one location. A broadband laser automatically has low temporal coherence. Collimation means that the rays in beam are parallel and do not diverge.

@RobertRapplean Sunlight is an example of light that is collimated, but has both low temporal and spatial coherence. Lasers often show all three of these properties and that's why it's easy to confuse them.

"Full spectrum" and "laser" do not directly combine, as lasers emit coherent light at selected wavelength. What @L.Dutch said about "white" lasers just means the scientists managed to combine three non-interfering lasers into one aligned superstructure that emits light at three separate wavelengths which is perceived as white. Lasers, however, still have a parameter named "laser linewidth" which ranges from several GHz to several kHz depending on laser technology and other factors. Thus, emitting full spectrum white laser light would require several thousand to several billion independent lasers whose frequencies cover the whole spectrum of visible light, with their emissions somehow coupled into one, which is not exactly possible unless they are really mounted like those three in that article in the answer above (link copied from there) due to general principle of optics which says that light path is fully reversible. Mounting several thousand lasers over a single axis would cause exponential losses of power to those lasers that are located "backwards", which would further damage the installation by being absorbed and turned into heat. So no, a "full-spectrum white" laser is impossible as is.
Limited spectrum "looks white" lasers have been built already, and a full-spectrum light source (not a laser) could be built based on plasma made of multiple chemical elements mixed up in a confined environment, to cover the absorption spectrum  of each, so that the resultant emission won't have wavelengths where light intensity is significantly lower than "nearby", aka dim lines in the total spectrum. The emitted light would have its spectrum pretty close to the theoretical curve of the true "black body radiation" spectrum based only on temperature of that black body. Still, as that Wiki article displays, the dim lines would still be present and detectable. In fact, such a torch would just behave like a segment of a star's photosphere with composition matching those we stuff into that plasma, with all its characteristics applied.
In total, you might settle for a limited spectrum "looks white" laser for those devices of yours, or ignore laser light properties and use white torches instead, depending on what do you need more, lasers or white.

""Full spectrum" and "laser" do not directly combine, as lasers emit coherent light at selected wavelength." This is not correct. Ultrashort lasers have a broad spectrum (see e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-05082-w, especially Fig. 1d which shows a spectrum spanning a full octave). The only requirement for a laser is to be coherent.

There are also free electron lasers, emitting in far-UV, with a very much nonmonochromatic spectrum, see e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15626

@Neinstein hmm FELs are something relatively new for me, they seem to use electrons to modulate light in order to attain coherence. They seem to have a broad but discrete spectrum, consisting of peaks at frequencies differing by a set value that depends on some factors unnown to me. Yes these seem to be able to satisfy the OP's requirement if their spectrum would be broad enough. Nice.

LASER is just coherent light emission and amplification. FELs just happen to do it very differently than an "ordinary" laser with an active medium, they wiggle the electrons just right to get what they want. All ultrashort light source wirks the same way: the shorter zou want to get, the wider spectrum you need. It's simple Fourier limit - a delta function has infinetly wide spectrum. Lasers are limited by the light oscillation period so you can only get down to few femtoseconds. FELs do the same but in the XUV regime so you can get attosecond pulses. The spectrum of FELs are...

... indeed very complex, but the ultrashort lasers are not that much better either (see ref 1). Actually you can get down to similar pulse lengths using femtosecond lasers as driving phenomena: if your light is very, very intense, it'll tear the electrons from an atom, accelerate it in vacuum, and throws it back to the core. When it collides, it emits a light with very, wide, distinct flat comb-like spectrum with high order (often 100+!) harmonics of the driving laser. This is called high harmonic generation (HHG) and is the cutting edge of ultrafast science. (Source: doing PhD on this)

Thank you for the answer, but I do now see the flaws with my choice of weaponry, and again, thank you for your time

This may be possible with very modern light technology.
To be a weapon, the laser beam must be focused into a very narrow, high-energy ray that stays thin while traveling a large distance. Any conventional optical system (be it a lens or mirror) requires electromagnetic waves to be close to a single wavelength to be focused into such a ray.
On the other hand, modern science may know how to build mirrors that are insensitive to wavelength in a wide range of the spectrum, like distributed Bragg reflectors or something more exotic, like "superconducting mirrors" (I cannot find a good source on these). Such mirrors may be able to focus a conventional light source into a narrow beam. For large, stationary weapons that can afford big mirrors, the Sun would be a source of white light.
I am not sure if such a weapon should still be called a "laser". Most of that makes a "laser" is about producing monochromatic light that any lens can focus.

"Any conventional optical system (be it a lens or mirror) requires electromagnetic waves to be close to a single wavelength to be focused into such a ray." Where are you getting this from?

Any lens is also a prism by design. It bends different wavelengths differently.

That's why reflecting telescopes exist: mirrors focus without regard to wavelength, provided the wavelength is one they are reflective at. However, high efficiency mirrors like dielectric mirrors are only effective across a limited range of wavelengths. Broadband mirrors will be less efficient, absorbing more of the light, and that's bad when you're dealing with enough light to damage a distant target. Also, your ability to focus the beam depends on wavelength: you will not be able to focus red light to as small a spot on the target as blue light.

@Nightrider Well, you mentioned mirrors yourself, and they don't have any chromatic aberration. There are also achromatic lenses which compensate for chromatic aberrations by combining two or more lenses of different materials.

@ChristopherJamesHuff Sure, you will have losses in your mirrors, but a laser is not 100% efficient either. If you're going to shoot a large amount of energy on to your enemy, you're going to have to design your weapon be able to deal with some of that energy dissipating inside it. That goes for virtually any weapon. Silver coatings, for instance, have >95% reflectance for practically all of the IR and visible bands.

@jkej and that's about as good as you can get for a broad band mirror. A dielectric mirror can do more like 99.999% at its design wavelength. And heat in the optical train is a bigger problem because thermal expansion will throw off the focus or aim.

Additionally, the concept of focusing sunlight into a beam is a non-starter, as the sun is not a point source. It's geometrically impossible to take all the possible paths for light across the sun's surface to your mirror's surface and make them parallel, or focus them to a point. To make a spot brighter than sunlight, your weapon would have to have a larger angular size as seen from the target than the sun. Worse, thermodynamics would still limit the maximum temperature to that of the sun.

This answer seems fundamentally misguided. You can align multiple lasers with a prism exactly because they have different colors. Basic idea: take a simple white beam source (non-laser), and see how the prism splits that beam into different colors. Now take all your monochrome lasers and mount them at the right position for their color. Light is reversible, so all laser beams will be aligned after the prism.

You would need unusual light source for that, not similar to light sources typically used

You've got two competing factors here.  In order to be a good weapon at space-combat distances you need the light to all be traveling in the same direction and not diverge too much.  You need a tightly-focused beam, not a floodlight.
This is what a "collimator" does.  It bounces the light back and forth a whole bunch of times until it's all headed in pretty much the same direction.
Collimators work really well on lasers, because there is only a single wavelength, so every photon bounces the same way.  This makes it very efficient to get them all lined up parallel to each other and "out the door."
And there's the competing factor.  You can still use a collimator on a broad-spectrum light source, but the different wavelengths will refract differently, so it's going to take some very clever engineering to get all the photons traveling in parallel lines without losing most of them as waste heat.
It will take even more clever engineering to be able to use any kind of mirrors or anything in your aiming system without ruining all the hard work the collimator has done, so you're probably going to have to gimble-mount the entire system.
And then you'll find that the beam scatters the instant it hits anything that has a refractive index, because the different colors all bend different amounts.  So it's not going to work well at all in an atmosphere, and ablative armor or anti-laser chaff will likely be quite effective against it.
Now, that said, the main problem with laser-based weaponry is efficiency. You're dumping more heat into your own ship than into the target, and that stacks up into quite a significant issue over the course of a battle.  So all this might be worth it if your broad-spectrum photon source is way more efficient than stimulated emission effects (The SE part of LASER.) and you can build a high-efficiency, broad-spectrum collimator.
Which...  You kind of can...  It's called a "casaba howitzer".  It's a nuclear shaped charge that converts about 85% of the blast into a 2.5 degree cone of broad-spectrum photons (traveling at the speed of light) and high energy plasma (traveling at about 20% of the speed of light if detonated in a vacuum.)
Basically it gets you away from the whole "nukes in space waste most of their force" complaint. The force concentration is over 2000X, even with the 15% conversion loss.  So a 1 megaton nuke hits like a 2 gigaton nuke along its beam path.  And at 20% of lightspeed it's definitely fast enough to count as a directed energy weapon for most purposes.

“White light” laser really means coherent over some broad spectral range.  You can achieve this by pumping a gain medium with a monochromatic laser to produce a temporally narrow pulse of light. Then by time/frequency uncertainty, this coherent packet must cover a range of frequencies.  The more narrow the pulse (in time) the broader the spectral range.  Eventually, your “white light” pulse would need to be very narrow in time…which is the dream of just about every ultrafast experiment. Typically, one can generate pulses that are ~15fs in width, but you’ll need about $1M in equipment and expertise in using such a laser.
